# Why my list is not getting updated when I select a new file and scan it?

Tags: java, arrays, string, parsing, actionlistener

I am doing a project where I need to parse a file and show the required words and do some manipulation of the output. So here is what happens. When I provide input file from my document folder which is like below:

```
input [5:0] gre1;
input wire           clock,    
           reset;   
input [3:0]    req3,           req2;  
input [3:0] req4, req5;        
input           req1;   
input           req0;   
output reg          gnt3,   
          gnt2,    
          gnt1; 
output [7:0] req43, req53;            
output          gnt0;
```

and I click start scan, it scans the file and stores the required words in an array, but when I select "clock" in the "specify clock" and "reset" in the "Specify reset signal", it is reading it properly and then I click start button, I get the output, but when I want to repeat the same procedure again by clicking "Go Back" and take another file which has different input like:

```
input [5:0] gre2;
input wire           clk,    
           rst;   
input [3:0]    req31,           req22;  
input [3:0] req42, req25;          
input           req12;   
input           req02;   
output reg          gnt23,   
          gnt22,    
          gnt12; 
output [7:0] req423, req523;              
output          gnt03;
```

then I click "start scan", it shows me the correct output, but then when I select "clk" in the Specify clock and "rst" in Specify the reset signal, it is still showing me the previous list of signals/words where I want the words/signals from my latest selected file.

My entire code is given below:

```
/**
 *
 * @author Mitesh Khadgi
 */

public class Main {
    private int maxFields = 52; // The max number of fields allowed in the dialog
    int count = 0;
    JComboBox relationCombo[] = new JComboBox[maxFields];
    String Signals[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
    JPanel comboPanel;
    JLabel opt;
    JLabel selSignal;
    JComboBox numOfSignals;
    String[] numSignals = {"1", "2"};

    JLabel handleLabel;
    JTextField handle;
    JComboBox Signal;
    JFrame guiFrame;
    private static final int PREF_W = 450;
    private static final int PREF_H = 450;

    //Note: Typically the main method will be in a
    //separate class. As this is a simple one class
    //example it's all in the one class.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Main();
    }

    public Main()
    {
        guiFrame = new JFrame();

        //make sure the program exits when the frame closes
        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setTitle("Assertion-Based GUI");
        guiFrame.setSize(500,500);

        //This will center the JFrame in the middle of the screen
        guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Panel for handle textfield option
        JPanel comboPanelNew = new JPanel();
        JTextField handleNew = new JTextField(30);
        comboPanelNew.add(handleNew);

        // Panel for input file and select and scan options.
        JPanel showPanel = new JPanel();
        JTextArea inoutlist = new JTextArea(5, 30);
        inoutlist.setEditable(false);
        inoutlist.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane scrollingAreaNew = new JScrollPane(inoutlist);
        showPanel.add(scrollingAreaNew);

        // Panel for clock, reset combobox options
        JPanel showPanelNew = new JPanel();
        opt = new JLabel("Specify a signal: ");
        Signal = new JComboBox(Signals);

        // Adding Panel for clock, reset combobox options in the showPanelNew.
        showPanelNew.add(opt);
        showPanelNew.add(Signal);

        JButton selectbutton = new JButton( "Select File");
        JButton scanbutton = new JButton( "Start Scan");

        selectbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
                    handleNew.setText(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        });

        scanbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                    List<String> listinputreal = new ArrayList<String>();

                    // Store file elements in this array called listinputreal.
                    System.out.println("LISTINPUTREAL: " + Arrays.toString(listinputreal.toArray()));

                    // Clock signal combobox listener to remove the clock signal from the inputsignallist.
                    Signal.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {                    
                // This list is not getting updated, when i click Go back and select a signal.
                    String[] inputsignalList = new String[] {};
                    for(int j = 0; j < listinputreal.size(); j++) {
                        inputsignalList[j] = listinputreal.toString();
                    }
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputsignalList));
            }
        });

                    String str = "qwerty1qwerty2";      
                    str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");

                    inoutlist.setText("OUTPUT");

            }
        });
        //The first JPanel contains a JLabel and JCombobox
        comboPanel = new JPanel();
        selSignal = new JLabel("Select number of signals: ");
        numOfSignals = new JComboBox(numSignals);
        handleLabel = new JLabel("Type a handle name: ");
        handle = new JTextField(20);

        //Create the second JPanel. Add a JLabel and JList and
        //make use the JPanel is not visible.
        final JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
        listPanel.setVisible(false);
        JLabel listLbl = new JLabel("Generated Code:");
        JTextArea vegs = new JTextArea(5, 30);
        vegs.setEditable(false);
        vegs.setLineWrap(true);

        listPanel.add(listLbl);
        JScrollPane scrollingArea = new JScrollPane(vegs);
        listPanel.add(scrollingArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // Adding new comboPanelNew, select, scan, textarea and clock, reset comboboxes to the existing comboPanel.
        comboPanel.add(comboPanelNew);
        comboPanel.add(selectbutton);
        comboPanel.add(scanbutton);
        comboPanel.add(showPanel);
        comboPanel.add(showPanelNew);

        // Adding selSignal label, numOfSignals combobox, handleLabel and handle textfield to comboPanel.
        comboPanel.add(selSignal);
        comboPanel.add(numOfSignals);
        comboPanel.add(handleLabel);
        comboPanel.add(handle);

        // Adding scrollpane to the comboPanel or guiFrame.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(comboPanel);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H));

        comboPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(comboPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JButton startbutton = new JButton( "START");

        //The ActionListener class is used to handle the
        //event that happens when the user clicks the button.
        //As there is not a lot that needs to happen we can 
        //define an anonymous inner class to make the code simpler.
        startbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
               //When the fruit of veg button is pressed
               //the setVisible value of the listPanel and
               //comboPanel is switched from true to 
               //value or vice versa.
               count++;
               // When the user clicks Go Back button, everything refreshes to new except the fileread and clock, reset options.
               if(count %2 == 0) {
                   startbutton.setText("START");
               }
               else {
                   startbutton.setText("Go Back");
               }
               }
            });
        //The JFrame uses the BorderLayout layout manager.
        //Put the two JPanels and JButton in different areas.

        guiFrame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        guiFrame.add(listPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        guiFrame.add(startbutton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //make sure the JFrame is visible
        guiFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't just dump your whole program into the question.

Comment: so much code post relevant part.

Comment: I have modified the code and posted relevant code.

Comment: In the link provided in the first comment it says *Minimal* although your code might be relevant, it isn't Minimal. Work on that first. Don't ignore comments, they are given to help you out but you have to do the work. Don't expect us to go over 100 lines of code to find that one statement that is wrong.

Comment: Please find my entire code to run from the link below:
https://github.com/mitshine/imspired/issues/1
Sorry but the code has become too large to make it minimal to understand. Therefore i am providing a link to my entire code since here i could not post the entire code.

Comment: The problem is in the "listinputreal", it is not getting updated when i take another file to scan and select "clock" in the Specify clock combobox. It still has the previous file values in it. is it due to the actionlistener called twice in nested form?